# objective-c turn parsed html elements into links in UITableViewCell

Tags: html, ios, objective-c, parsing, uitableview

I followed the tutorial here:
http://www.raywenderlich.com/14172/how-to-parse-html-on-ios

One of the challenges was to then:
"Make the phone open Safari to that tutorial’s or contributor’s URL when you tap on each row?"

How would I do this to make the dynamic parsed data the link of each UITableViewCell?
What would the difference in code be between opening in a browser and opening within the app?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To Open URL in Safari you need to: 
 1. Create string with URL.

```
NSString *urlString =@"http://www.google.com";
```

2. Open it with this method of UIApplication

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication]openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

**OR**

If you want to open link inside you app you need.
1. Create WebView and set it delegate(optional if you want to control load process).

```
UIWebView *webView =[[UIWebView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectInset(self.view.frame, 10, 10)];
```

2. Create URL request

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
```

3. Add WebView as a subview

```
[self.view addSubview:web view];
```

4. Load you request

```
[webView loadRequest:request];
```

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:tutorialURL];
```